# PHP XPath and Line Numbers

Tags: php, xpath

The following xpath works, but how can i get the **line number** at which the xpath finds the p element with class 'blah'?

```
<?php    
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<p class='blah'>some text here</p>
</body>

</html>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath_query = "//*[contains(@class, 'blah')]";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath and DOM have no concept of a line number. They only see nodes, and the linkages between them.

The DOM object itself may have some internal metadata which can relate a node back to which line it was on in the source file, but you'd have to rummage around inside the object and the DOM source to find out. Doesn't seem to be anything mentioned at http://php.net/dom.

Alternatively, if the node you're looking at, and/or the surrounding HTML is fairly/totally unique in the document, you could search the raw html for the matching HTML text of the node and get a line number that way.

Comment: Cheers Marc, guess i'll have to go with search raw html.